# How do I "join" in awk, or otherwise trim a trailing /?

Tags: awk, sed

```bsh
 echo -n "refs/heads/feature" | awk -F '/' -v OFS='/' '{ print $3, $4 }' | sed 's/\/$/g'
sed: 1: "s/\/$/g": unterminated substitute in regular expression
```

if I removed the sed this would print `feature/` I just want `feature` but if it were

```bsh
echo -n "refs/heads/feature/foo" | awk -F '/' -v OFS='/' '{ print $3, $4 }'
```

I would want `feature/foo`

this is for a github actions workflow, and I'm getting the `git` ref from `GITHUB_REF` env var, and intend to assign it to another one.

Comment: I think you need to use `'s/\\/$/g'`

Comment: @rfmodulator that would replace a literal backslash with a literal dollar sign - I think what the OP was shooting for is `sed 's/\/$//g'`

Comment: @steeldriver probably so

Comment: ... although of course the `g` modifier is meaningless when the RE is anchored to `$`

Comment: Is https://stackoverflow.com/q/58033366/10488700 related? The suggestion I'd take from there is `${GITHUB_REF#refs/heads/}`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$ echo -n "refs/heads/feature" | awk -F '/' '{ print $3 (NF>3 ? FS $4 : "")}'
feature

$ echo -n "refs/heads/feature/foo" | awk -F '/' '{ print $3 (NF>3 ? FS $4 : "")}'
feature/foo
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `cut` for this: using slash as the delimiter, print from the 3rd to the last fields:

```bsh
while read branch; do
    echo "$branch" | cut -d/ -f3-
done <<END
refs/heads/feature
refs/heads/feature/foo
END
```

outputs

```
feature
feature/foo
```

You could also use `-f3-4` or `-f3,4` if you only want the 3rd and 4th fields.

Comment: No need for a loop, `cut` will take a line at a time on it's own: `cut -d/ -f3- <<...`

Answer (score 0):

We dynamically set the value of OFS depending on whether fields are more than 3.

```
$ awk '
  BEGIN { a[1] = FS = "/" }
  {
    OFS = a[(NF>3)]
    print $3, $4
  }
' file
```